# org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Part content ID cannot be blank for non root MIME parts

Tags: maven-2, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to build WSO2-4.4.1 through Maven-2.2.1 when i run command mvn clean install >Wso2Log.txt it will run 10-20 hr after that it will give error build faild error.

If any one have some valuable time please help me thanx.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.
Please refer to /home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/saaj/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 869 minutes 47 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 08 18:03:03 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 407M/2727M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
My  Individual test result is given bellow 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite failures="0" time="7.535" errors="1" skipped="0" tests="7" name="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest">
  <properties>
    <property name="java.vendor" value="Sun Microsystems Inc."/>
    <property name="javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory" value="org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPFactoryImpl"/>
    <property name="env.LESSOPEN" value="|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s"/>
    <property name="localRepository" value="/home/uddi/.m2/repository"/>
    <property name="env.ORACLE_HOME" value="/home/uddi/app/uddi/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1"/>
    <property name="sun.java.launcher" value="SUN_STANDARD"/>
    <property name="sun.management.compiler" value="HotSpot Tiered Compilers"/>
    <property name="os.name" value="Linux"/>
    <property name="sun.boot.class.path" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/classes"/>
    <property name="env.PWD" value="/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src"/>
    <property name="env.ORACLE_SID" value="orcl"/>
    <property name="env.LANG" value="en_US.UTF-8"/>
    <property name="java.vm.specification.vendor" value="Sun Microsystems Inc."/>
    <property name="java.runtime.version" value="1.6.0_25-b06"/>
    <property name="env.HISTSIZE" value="1000"/>
    <property name="user.name" value="uddi"/>
    <property name="env.USER" value="uddi"/>
    <property name="env.SHELL" value="/bin/bash"/>
    <property name="env.KDEDIR" value="/usr"/>
    <property name="env.QTLIB" value="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib"/>
    <property name="env.SSH_TTY" value="/dev/pts/4"/>
    <property name="env.NLSPATH" value="/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat"/>
    <property name="javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory" value="org.apache.axis2.saaj.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl"/>
    <property name="env.PATH" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/bin:.:/home/uddi/mpf/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin:/home/uddi/mpf/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/bin:.:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/uddi/bin"/>
    <property name="user.language" value="en"/>
    <property name="sun.boot.library.path" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386"/>
    <property name="classworlds.conf" value="/home/uddi/mpf/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin/m2.conf"/>
    <property name="env.SSH_CONNECTION" value="172.16.16.117 49123 172.16.16.18 22"/>
    <property name="java.version" value="1.6.0_25"/>
    <property name="env.SSH_CLIENT" value="172.16.16.117 49123 22"/>
    <property name="user.timezone" value="Asia/Calcutta"/>
    <property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="32"/>
    <property name="java.endorsed.dirs" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/endorsed"/>
    <property name="sun.cpu.isalist" value=""/>
    <property name="sun.jnu.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io"/>
    <property name="env.SHLVL" value="1"/>
    <property name="file.separator" value="/"/>
    <property name="env.HOSTNAME" value="ssdg3"/>
    <property name="java.specification.name" value="Java Platform API Specification"/>
    <property name="env.QTDIR" value="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3"/>
    <property name="java.class.version" value="50.0"/>
    <property name="user.country" value="US"/>
    <property name="java.home" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre"/>
    <property name="java.vm.info" value="mixed mode"/>
    <property name="env.LOGNAME" value="uddi"/>
    <property name="os.version" value="2.6.18-194.el5"/>
    <property name="env.G_BROKEN_FILENAMES" value="1"/>
    <property name="path.separator" value=":"/>
    <property name="java.vm.version" value="20.0-b11"/>
    <property name="env.QTINC" value="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/include"/>
    <property name="env.JAVA_HOME" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25"/>
    <property name="java.awt.printerjob" value="sun.print.PSPrinterJob"/>
    <property name="env.TERM" value="xterm"/>
    <property name="sun.io.unicode.encoding" value="UnicodeLittle"/>
    <property name="user.home" value="/home/uddi"/>
    <property name="java.specification.vendor" value="Sun Microsystems Inc."/>
    <property name="env.M2_HOME" value="/home/uddi/mpf/apache-maven-2.2.1"/>
    <property name="java.library.path" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib"/>
    <property name="java.vendor.url" value="http://java.sun.com/"/>
    <property name="java.vm.vendor" value="Sun Microsystems Inc."/>
    <property name="maven.home" value="/home/uddi/mpf/apache-maven-2.2.1"/>
    <property name="java.runtime.name" value="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment"/>
    <property name="sun.java.command" value="org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher &quot;clean&quot; &quot;install&quot;"/>
    <property name="java.class.path" value="/home/uddi/mpf/apache-maven-2.2.1/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar"/>
    <property name="env.CVS_RSH" value="ssh"/>
    <property name="env.XFILESEARCHPATH" value="/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt"/>
    <property name="java.vm.specification.name" value="Java Virtual Machine Specification"/>
    <property name="java.vm.specification.version" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="sun.os.patch.level" value="unknown"/>
    <property name="sun.cpu.endian" value="little"/>
    <property name="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration" value="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeParserConfiguration"/>
    <property name="java.awt.headless" value="true"/>
    <property name="env.HOME" value="/home/uddi"/>
    <property name="env.ANT_HOME" value="/home/uddi/mpf/apache-ant-1.8.4"/>
    <property name="surefire.test.class.path" value="/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/saaj/target/test-classes:/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/saaj/target/classes:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-saaj_1.3_spec/1.0.1/geronimo-saaj_1.3_spec-1.0.1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/commons/axiom/axiom-dom/1.2.11/axiom-dom-1.2.11.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/commons/axiom/axiom-api/1.2.11/axiom-api-1.2.11.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec/1.0.2/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec/1.6/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.1/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec/1.0.1/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.9/wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/adb/target/axis2-adb-1.6.1-wso2v1.jar:/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/kernel/target/axis2-kernel-1.6.1-wso2v1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/commons/axiom/axiom-impl/1.2.11/axiom-impl-1.2.11.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec/1.1.2/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.3/servlet-api-2.3.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2/commons-fileupload-1.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.2/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.7-wso2v1/XmlSchema-1.4.7-wso2v1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/neethi/neethi/2.0.4/neethi-2.0.4.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/woden/woden-api/1.0M9/woden-api-1.0M9.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/woden/woden-impl-dom/1.0M9/woden-impl-dom-1.0M9.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/woden/woden-impl-commons/1.0M9/woden-impl-commons-1.0M9.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.0/jsr311-api-1.0.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/wso2/securevault/org.wso2.securevault/1.0.0/org.wso2.securevault-1.0.0.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.4/junit-4.4.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/axis2/axis2-transport-http/1.6.1-wso2v1/axis2-transport-http-1.6.1-wso2v1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0/httpcore-4.0.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/org/apache/axis2/axis2-transport-local/1.6.1-wso2v1/axis2-transport-local-1.6.1-wso2v1.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/xmlunit/xmlunit/1.3/xmlunit-1.3.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/jetty/jetty/5.1.10/jetty-5.1.10.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.2/saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/parsers/jaxp-ri/1.4.2/jaxp-ri-1.4.2.jar:/home/uddi/.m2/repository/javax/xml/parsers/jaxp-api/1.4.2/jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar:"/>
    <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="/tmp"/>
    <property name="env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/i386:/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/../lib/i386"/>
    <property name="env.LS_COLORS" value="no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:"/>
    <property name="java.vendor.url.bug" value="http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi"/>
    <property name="env.MAVEN_OPTS" value="-Xms256m -Xmx3072m"/>
    <property name="env.KDE_NO_IPV6" value="1"/>
    <property name="java.awt.graphicsenv" value="sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment"/>
    <property name="os.arch" value="i386"/>
    <property name="java.ext.dirs" value="/home/uddi/mpf/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext"/>
    <property name="user.dir" value="/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/saaj"/>
    <property name="line.separator" value="
"/>
    <property name="env.INPUTRC" value="/etc/inputrc"/>
    <property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM"/>
    <property name="basedir" value="/home/uddi/mpf/wso2greg-4.1.1-src/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v1/modules/saaj"/>
    <property name="javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory" value="org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl"/>
    <property name="env.M2" value="/home/uddi/mpf/apache-maven-2.2.1/bin"/>
    <property name="javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory" value="org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPConnectionFactoryImpl"/>
    <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="env.MAIL" value="/var/spool/mail/uddi"/>
    <property name="java.specification.version" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="env.KDE_IS_PRELINKED" value="1"/>
    <property name="env.SSH_ASKPASS" value="/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass"/>
  </properties>
  <testcase time="0.236" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testSendReceiveMessageWithEmptyNSPrefix"/>
  <testcase time="0.039" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testSendReceiveSimpleSOAPMessage"/>
  <testcase time="0.072" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testSendReceiveMessageWithAttachment"/>
  <testcase time="0.036" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testSendReceive_ISO88591_EncodedSOAPMessage"/>
  <testcase time="0.024" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testCallWithSOAPAction"/>
  <testcase time="0.023" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testCallMTOM">
    <error message="org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Part content ID cannot be blank for non root MIME parts" type="javax.xml.soap.SOAPException">javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Part content ID cannot be blank for non root MIME parts
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SOAPMessageImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest.testCallMTOM(IntegrationTest.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SAAJTestRunner.invokeTestMethod(SAAJTestRunner.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: Part content ID cannot be blank for non root MIME parts
    at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.getNextPartDataHandler(Attachments.java:648)
    at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.getDataHandler(Attachments.java:350)
    at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.&lt;init&gt;(Attachments.java:247)
    at org.apache.axiom.attachments.Attachments.&lt;init&gt;(Attachments.java:267)
    at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.&lt;init&gt;(SOAPMessageImpl.java:84)
    ... 29 more
</error>
  </testcase>
  <testcase time="2.043" classname="org.apache.axis2.saaj.integration.IntegrationTest" name="testConnectionCleanup"/>
</testsuite>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems test failure, try with:

```
mvn <commands> -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Regards,